# JSF 1.2 to 2.0 migration exception with el-api.jar

Tags: jsf, websphere-7

We are migrating our application which was developed using JSF1.2 to JSF2.0 on WAS7 .Also we have decided to use view technology as JSP. We have made the required changes(jars,web.xmland faces-config.xml) as suggested in:

[Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

We are also using richfaces components and we have upgraded library to richfaces3.3.3.

We are getting following exception while using h:commandlink and h:commandbutton:

```
Exception created : javax.servlet.ServletException
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:325)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1597)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
                at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
                at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
                at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
                at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
                at org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:341)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
                at com.xxx.yyy.webapp.security.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:201)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:908)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:934)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
                at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
                at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
                at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
                at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
                at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
                at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
                at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
                at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1646)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
                at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getELContext(FacesContext.java:223)
                at javax.faces.application.NavigationCase.getToViewId(NavigationCase.java:264)
                at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.determineViewFromActionOutcome(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:580)
                at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.findExactMatch(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:345)
                at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.getViewId(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:279)
                at com.sun.faces.application.NavigationHandlerImpl.handleNavigation(NavigationHandlerImpl.java:159)
                at org.apache.myfaces.custom.redirectTracker.RedirectTrackerNavigationHandler.handleNavigation(RedirectTrackerNavigationHandler.java:40)
                at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:130)
                at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
                at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxActionComponent.broadcast(AjaxActionComponent.java:55)
                at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processEvents(AjaxViewRoot.java:329)
                at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.broadcastEventsForPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:304)
                at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processPhase(AjaxViewRoot.java:261)
                at org.ajax4jsf.component.AjaxViewRoot.processApplication(AjaxViewRoot.java:474)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:82)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:312)
```

Root causes seems to be related to expression language.We do not have el-api.jar in our WEB-INF/lib as recommended and we have set classloader policy to PARENT_LAST at both server and application level. WAS7 has j2ee5 jar in its lib directory.

Comment: This indeed suggests a conflict between old JSF impl and newer JSF impl. Setting `PARENT_LAST` should fix it. Not sure why it didn't do it for you.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for quick response.. yes you are correct setting PARENT_LAST is the fix.. for from WAS console some how PARENT_LAST dint get set in manage modules.. also after removing <t:savestate> from .jsp files we forgot to remove tomhawk-sandbox jar. Hence the issue fixed for us.